# How can I execute a extension from the vendor’s bin folder?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, magerun

Hi I install a  extension magerun2 using composer which is install in vendor . now how I can execute it from vendor as on root director it is showing no command found

Manual for this is `https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2`

```
Install with Composer 
Require Magerun within the Magento (or any other) `project and you can then execute it from the vendor’s bin folder:`
composer require n98/magerun2
# ...
./vendor/bin/n98-magerun2 --version
n98-magerun2 version 1.3.2 by netz98 GmbH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following `php vendor/bin/n98-magerun2 --version`

Comment: btw I already figure out by going into vendor and then bin then..    ./n98-magerun2 --version